# Array used for recyclerview item doubled

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I just make a recyclerview and the data is doubled with this logic :

```
  if(itemsList != null)
            {
                while (itemsList.hasNext()) {
                    val inFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                    val outFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm")

                    val inFormatTwo: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'")
                    val outFormatTwo: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
                        val detail = itemsList.iterator().next().listIterator()
                        while(detail.hasNext())
                            {
                            val item = detail.next()
                            val status = item.status
                            val type = item.itemType
                            val pickupPoint = item.pickupPoint
                            val name = item.requesterDetails.elementAt(0).name
                            val reqDate = item.requestDate
                            val pickupTime = item.pickupTime
                            val reviewDate = item.pickupTime
                            val purpose = item.rejectReason
                            val quantity = item.quantity
                            val isActive = item.isActive
                            val isLatest = item.isLatest
                            var itemList : Any

                                val reqDateFormatted : Date?
                                val reqDateFix : String

                                reqDateFormatted = inFormat.parse(reqDate)
                                reqDateFix = outFormat.format(reqDateFormatted!!)

                                var pickupTimeFormatted : Date?
                                var pickupTimeFix = ""

                                if(pickupTime.length == 24)
                                {
                                    pickupTimeFormatted = inFormat.parse(pickupTime)
                                    pickupTimeFix = outFormat.format(pickupTimeFormatted)
                                } else if(pickupTime.length == 20)
                                {
                                    pickupTimeFormatted = inFormatTwo.parse(pickupTime)
                                    pickupTimeFix = outFormatTwo.format(pickupTimeFormatted!!)
                                }

                                if(isLatest == "Y")
                                {
                                    itemList = DataModel(
                                        type + " Request",
                                        status,
                                        name,
                                        type,
                                        quantity.toString(),
                                        reqDateFix,
                                        reviewDate,
                                        pickupPoint,
                                        pickupTimeFix,
                                        purpose,
                                        isActive,
                                        isLatest
                                    )
                                    itemsData.add(itemList)
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                }
                            }
            }
            }
```

Basically, it is used to inform the user of the item they request, so the data comes from API. So, if itemsList is not null then while itemsList array has elements and inside it also exists array(s) and inside the array, I add each string to ArrayList and then isLatest string is equal to Y then add those arrays to itemList as a DataModel and then save them by adding itemList to itemsData. What makes the array doubled, thank you for your help

Comment: What do u mean by array is doubled? Can u add the final array?

Comment: let's say if I have 2 status data from backend it must be displaying just those 2 status data but the data displayed in recyclerview is repeated and when I check using Log after if(itemsList != null) itemsData execute twice (doubled). If and for loop located inside         getData.observe(this, Observer {**here**})
@fatalcoder524

Answer (score 0):

Notify the changes to adapter after the while loop and not after each add.

Try this:

```
 if(itemsList != null)
            {
                while (itemsList.hasNext()) {
                    val inFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                    val outFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm")

                    val inFormatTwo: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'")
                    val outFormatTwo: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
                        val detail = itemsList.iterator().next().listIterator()
                        while(detail.hasNext())
                            {
                            val item = detail.next()
                            val status = item.status
                            val type = item.itemType
                            val pickupPoint = item.pickupPoint
                            val name = item.requesterDetails.elementAt(0).name
                            val reqDate = item.requestDate
                            val pickupTime = item.pickupTime
                            val reviewDate = item.pickupTime
                            val purpose = item.rejectReason
                            val quantity = item.quantity
                            val isActive = item.isActive
                            val isLatest = item.isLatest
                            var itemList : Any

                                val reqDateFormatted : Date?
                                val reqDateFix : String

                                reqDateFormatted = inFormat.parse(reqDate)
                                reqDateFix = outFormat.format(reqDateFormatted!!)

                                var pickupTimeFormatted : Date?
                                var pickupTimeFix = ""

                                if(pickupTime.length == 24)
                                {
                                    pickupTimeFormatted = inFormat.parse(pickupTime)
                                    pickupTimeFix = outFormat.format(pickupTimeFormatted)
                                } else if(pickupTime.length == 20)
                                {
                                    pickupTimeFormatted = inFormatTwo.parse(pickupTime)
                                    pickupTimeFix = outFormatTwo.format(pickupTimeFormatted!!)
                                }

                                if(isLatest == "Y")
                                {
                                    itemList = DataModel(
                                        type + " Request",
                                        status,
                                        name,
                                        type,
                                        quantity.toString(),
                                        reqDateFix,
                                        reviewDate,
                                        pickupPoint,
                                        pickupTimeFix,
                                        purpose,
                                        isActive,
                                        isLatest
                                    )
                                    itemsData.add(itemList)
                                    
                                }
                            }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
```

Comment: Still, nothing changed.